# Advice about webapp architecture and reactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, elasticsearch, reactjs

This question is more to know your opinions about the way I'm trying to solve this issue.
I would need a little bit of ReactJs expertise here as I'm quite new.

First a little bit of context. I'm developing a web application using ReactJs for the frontend part.
This webapp is going to have many translations, so for maintenance I thought it would be better to store all the translations in a database instead of having them into a file. This way I could manage them using sql scripts.

I'm using a MySQL database for the backend, but for performance reasons, I have added ElasticSearch as second database (well, it is more a full text search engine).

So once the application starts, the translations are automatically loaded into ElasticSearch. Every translation has a code, and a text, so in elastic search I only load the translations for one locale (by default english), and when a user switchs the locale, a call is done to load all the translations for the selected locale and update their corresponding text.

This way from the fronted I can reference a translation only by the code and I will get the text translated in the correct locale.

Now, how do I do that in react?

So far I have written a component TranslatedMessage which is basically looking for a given code and displaying it whereever this component is rendered.

Below the code of the component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class TranslatedMessage extends React.Component {


constructor() {
    super();
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.state = {message: ''};
}

render() {
    return (<div>{this.state.message}</div>);
}

componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    var code=this.props.code;
    var url="data/translation?code="+code;
    $.get(url, function (result) {
        component.setState({message: result.text});
    });
 }

};
```

And then I use it in the application whis way, for example to translate the title of an 'a' link:

```
  <a href="index"><TranslatedMessage code="lng.dropdown.home"/><i className="fa fa-chevron-down" /></a>
```

So far is working fine but the problem is that I need to refresh the whole page to get the new translations displayed, because I'm not updating the state of the component.

So now my questions:

1)Every time that we find in a page the component TranslatedMessage, a new instance of that component is created right? so basically if I have 1000 translations, 1000 instances of that component will be created? And then React has to take care and watch all these instances for changes in the state? Would that be very bad for performance? Do you find any more efficient way to do it?

2) I don't think forcing the whole page to reload is the most proper way to do it, but how can I update the states of all that components when a user switch the locale? I've been reading about a framework (or pattern) called Flux, and maybe that could fit my needs, what do you thing, would you recommend it?

3) What do you think about storing translations on db, I'm a bit concern about sending a query to the db for every translation, would you recommend or not this approach?

Any suggestions, ideas for improvement are very welcome!

Thank you for taking your time to read it or for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use what is basically a Flux store for this purpose. On initialisation the application requests the whole language file to use (which is JSON) and that gets shoved into memory in the store, something like this (I'm going to assume a totally flat language file for now, and I'm using ES2015/16 syntax, I've omitted error checking etc etc for brevity):

```
class I18n {
  constructor() {
    this.lang = await fetch( 'lang_endpoint' )
      .then( res => res.json() )
  }

  get( translation ) {
    return this.lang[ translation ] || null
  }
}
```

Somewhere my app starts during a `ReactDOM.render( <App /> )` or some variation and this renders the whole thing top-down (I try to eliminate state as much as possible). If I needed to switch languages then I'd bind a `change` handler such that the store emits a `change` event which is heard by some code that triggers a `ReactDOM.render`. This is fairly standard Flux practise for changing the app state, the key is to try and eliminate state from your components and store it inside your stores.

To use the `I18n` class simply instantiate it somewhere (I normally have it as a singleton exported from a file, e.g. `module.exports = new I18n()`, `require` that file into your components and use the `get` method (this assumes some sort of packager such as browserify or webpack but it looks like you have that complexity all sorted):

```
import 'i18n' from 'stores/i18n'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() { ... }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>{ i18n.get( 'title' ) }</span>
    )
  }
}
```

This component could also be simplified to

```
const MyComponent = props => <span>{ i18n.get( 'title' ) }</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one question more, to use await the function has to be marked as async, but constructors can't be async, how do you solve that?

Comment: its in the constructor just for brevity. I'd extract that load section to a separate function and call that after constructing the store. Slightly fudgey but works just fine. Alternatively you could use promises and have the store emit when it is loaded/ready, this is effectively a data change so I'd just emit the change event that you're already handling to re-render your app.